# How to get iPython inbuild magic command to work in Jupyter notebook Pyspark kernel?

Tags: matplotlib, ipython, pyspark, jupyter, apache-toree

I am using `PySpark` kernel installed through `Apache Toree` in `Jupyter Notebook` using `Anaconda v4.0.0` (`Python 2.7.11`). After getting a table from `Hive`, use `matplotlib/panda` to plot some graph in Jupyter notebook, following the tutorial as below:

```
%matplotlib inline
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# Set some Pandas options
pd.set_option('display.notebook_repr_html', False)
pd.set_option('display.max_columns', 20)
pd.set_option('display.max_rows', 25)

normals = pd.Series(np.random.normal(size=10))
normals.plot()
```

I was stuck at the first link when I tried to use %matplotlib inline which shows

```
Name: Error parsing magics!
Message: Magics [matplotlib] do not exist!
StackTrace:
```

Looking at [Toree Magic](https://github.com/apache/incubator-toree/blob/01936c1da63f1a13a93ab0c19fca015864c7ee5c/etc/examples/notebooks/magic-tutorial.ipynb) and [MagicManager](https://github.com/apache/incubator-toree/blob/01936c1da63f1a13a93ab0c19fca015864c7ee5c/kernel-api/src/main/scala/org/apache/toree/magic/MagicManager.scala), I realised that `%matplotlib` is calling `MagicManager` instead of the `iPython` in-build magic command.

Is it possible for `Apache Toree - PySpark` to use iPython in-build magic command instead?

Comment: Install `matplotlib`?

Comment: @zero323 I can import `matplotlib` but when I try to run `%matplotlib inline` on the Jupyter notebook console shows `16/09/20 09:40:24 ERROR magic.MagicManager: No magic found for matplotlib` Is there a way to get iPython magic to work?

Answer (score 1):

I did a workaround hack for PySpark and magic command to work, instead of installing `Toree PySpark kernel` I am using `PySpark directly on Jupyter Notebook`.

1. Download and install `Anaconda2 4.0.0`
2. Download `Spark 1.6.0` pre-built for `Hadoop 2.6`
3. Append `~/.bashrc` with the following commands and enter `source ~/.bashrc` to update environment variables

   # added to run spark
   export PATH="{your_spark_dir}spark/sbin:$PATH"
   export PATH="{your_spark_dir}spark/bin:$PATH"

   # added to launch spark application in cluster mode
   export JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre

   # next 2 lines are optional, needed only Spark Cluster
   export HADOOP_CONF_DIR={your_hadoop_conf}/hadoop-conf
   export YARN_CONF_DIR={your_hadoop_conf}/hadoop-conf

   # added by Anaconda2 4.0.0 installer
   export PATH="{your_anaconda_dir}/Anaconda/bin:$PATH"

   # added to run pyspark in jupyter notebook
   export PYSPARK_DRIVER_PYTHON={your_anaconda_dir}/Anaconda/bin/jupyter
   export PYSPARK_DRIVER_PYTHON_OPTS="notebook --NotebookApp.open_browser=False --NotebookApp.ip='0.0.0.0' --NotebookApp.port=8888"
   export PYSPARK_PYTHON={your_anaconda_dir}/Anaconda/bin/python

**Running the Jupyter Notebook**

1. `pyspark --master=yarn --deploy-mode=client` to start the notebook running `PySpark in cluster mode`
2. Open a browser and enter `IP_ADDRESS_OF_COMPUTER:8888`

**Disclaimer**
This is only a workaround and not an actual way of fixing the problem please let me know if you found a way for `Toree PySpark` ipython inbuild magic command to work. Magic command such as `%matplotlib notebook`